# Profile2 Statistics

Tags: views, users, nodes

Is there any module that would help me to see statistics and also use them as filter/sorting criteria in views of profile2 pages ? I mean as is the core module statistics and i can add filters like content:total views or anything similar ,is there a module which offers the same data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [user visits](http://drupal.org/project/user_visits) module.

The user Visits module tracks visits and referer from other users on a user's profile page.
It displays the latest visitors on a user's profile page and provides two blocks one with the latest visitors on a user's profile page and one with the latest visitors on own profile page.

You can create your own module to filter afterwards using the data provided by the above module.

Check this mdoule also [User visits Advanced](http://drupal.org/project/user_visits_adv)

Comment: The thing is that i do not need blocks of statistics , i need the statistics to be used as filter criteria in views!!!

Comment: you can alter the query of the view.

Comment: can you provide an example ?